# Regarding significance of synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

This might be a dumb question to ask but I am new to multi-threaded programming in Java.I created 4 threads and then invoked the run method on them.In the run method I am using an array and am assigning values to it's indices.I see that each thread is maintaining it's own copy of the array and there is no thread-unsafe behavior. I just wanted to know that in this case what is the significance of using synchronization?(I thought it was used to control access to a shared resource.Isn't the array supposed to be a shared data structure here?)

Answer (score 2):

No -- if each thread uses its own copy of the array, then you have four separate arrays that happen to contain the same data, but no sharing is happening.

Sharing would be if you had *one* array, and all four threads operated on that array, with at least the potential for two threads to use the same data at the same time. In such a case you would need synchronization to assure that only one of them tried (for example) to write to any specific location at any one time (or that if one was reading and another writing, that the writing was done atomically, with the read happening either completely before the write, or else completely after it -- but the two would not be allowed to overlap).

Comment: Apart from bad programming style what are the cons of writing all the functionality in the run method? If I create and use all the data- structures within the run method then each thread will maintain it's own copy of the structure and no synchronization will be required.

Comment: Putting all the code in the run method vs. splitting it up across a number of other functions should *not* have any significant effect on requirement for synchronization (or lack thereof).

Comment: Performance wise which will be faster,sharing the data structures or each thread having it's own data structure? Also,which is better programming style or it depends on the context? I am assuming there will be memory overhead when each thread maintains an individual copy of the resources?

Comment: @simpleguy: it depends. Copying the data takes time. So does waiting for another thread. The time to copy is a (more or less) fixed up-front cost, whereas the waiting is an ongoing cost, and depends on how often different threads contend over the same data. As to which is better, it also depends. If you want a change in one thread to be visible to other threads, you just about have to share the data. If not, copying the data can be a lot simpler and (especially if all threads access the data similarly) can improve speed as well.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you are absolutely sure that the arrays are COMPLETELY different (need to be careful here as there can be pointers to the same object depending on what you've done) then you don't need to synchronize the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your threads only perform operations on their own private data, then no synchronization is necessary.

By the way, you say you "invoked the run method" on your threads; calling Thread.run() directly won't execute your logic in a new thread though; you'll want to call Thread.start() instead (which internally executes run() in a separate thread).

Comment: Yes,my bad there.I am calling Thread.start() which in turn calls run()

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "In the run method I am using an array " (stress on using)? If you have passed the reference of array to thread then yes, sync will prevent simultaneous access to the array.However, if you create an instance on array in the Thread, then you have 4 separate instance of array and synchronization has no effect.

Comment: I am creating an array inside the run method.If sync is not required in the current context then what is the point of having it? I know it's bad programming style to write all the functionality in the run method but what will be the main issue?

Comment: In your current context you can just drop sync since you have separate copy of array. If you want to use sync, you can declare array in a common place (main class from where you spawned 4 threads or make array as member variable of another class and then pass instance of the class to threads). You can declare a method with sync and then do all heavy weight activity in it. Just call this method in run, since it is sync. only one thread will be able to execute it at any one point of time.

Comment: This means if I create and use all the data- structures within the run method then each thread will maintain it's own copy of the structure and no synchronization will be required?

Comment: That's right. Run is a method, variable declared inside it is within the scope of the method.